# Writing an ember-cli addon in Coffeescript

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, preprocessor, ember-cli

I'm trying to author an ember-cli addon, and I prefer to develop in Coffeescript. But it seems like the CLI build is hardcoded to look for just .js files. Is there any way to author an addon in Coffeescript and have the build take place with the consuming application's build (i.e. without me having to build the addon each time using a custom build process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out this is a bug in the CLI, but it wasn't fixed in 0.0.47. See https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2354 for more context, it's currently an open issue & PR.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can author in Coffeescript, but there was a bug in 0.0.46 where we would only preprocess `*.js` files in the `addon` tree.  This is fixed on master, and should be included in 0.0.47 soonish...

Comment: So I'm using 0.1.1 now, and while the app folder works fine with coffeescript, the addon folder doesn't (I get ENOENT errors saying it can't find my-addon-name/file-in-addon-folder.js). With some digging, it seems like the jsGlob doesn't include '.coffee' - there seems to be some issue with loading the ember-cli-coffeescript preprocessor. I realize this is kind of vague - would any debug information be helpful here? Or even suggestions for where to start looking?